# How do you set the number of lags to test in the statsmodels ADF test?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I know you can specify maxlags in the parameters, but whenever I do the output shows that I am using zero lags. Here's a generic example of the problem I'm having. I set maxlag = 1 in this example. The result however shows that the number of lags used is 0, corresponding to the third parameter in the output.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as ts

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,3,4,2,3])
result = ts.adfuller(x, 1) # maxlag is now set to 1

>>> result
(-2.6825663173365015, 0.077103947319183241, 0, 7, {'5%': -3.4775828571428571, '1%': -4.9386902332361515, '10%': -2.8438679591836733}, 15.971188911270618)
```

I'm thinking there is some built-in determining factor for the number of lags based off my input for the maxlag parameter, but I wasn't able to find anything online.

Could someone please explain this, and possibly how to make the ADF test run with the number of lags I want to input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxlag` is the largest lag that is used for the `autolag` search.

By default the number of lags that are chosen is determined by the smallest AIC for all lags up to maxlag. If you want to have a fixed number of lags, then you need to use `autolag=None` as argument.

see the docstring http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.adfuller.html

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. Really appreciate the help.